# What packages are needed on CentOS to compile MapServer from source

Tags: mapserver, centos, compilation

I'm trying to `configure` MapServer 6.2.0 for compilation on CentOS 6.3, but always run into the same problem, no matter what configure options I supply (also the same with no options at all, just plain configure).

It has something to do with g++ (although I do not really understand why it tries to use it).

Here is the output:

http://pastebin.com/8H5vmrPi

What is wrong?

**EDIT**: This problem was solved with `yum install gcc-c++`, as suggested by @steko. Now, I have another error, which is weird in my opinion:

```
configure: checking whether we should include PROJ.4 support...
configure: error: "Could not find proj_api.h or libproj.a/libproj.so in /usr/lib64."
```

Although `locate proj_api.h` gives `/usr/include/proj_api.h` (I also set `--with-proj=/usr/include` for configure, not as in the paste bin).

Comment: Re: proj, according to http://www.mapserver.org/installation/unix.html#compiling you should only do `--with-proj=/usr` or `--with-proj=/usr/local` respectively if installed from package or from source.

Comment: `--with-proj=/usr` did the trick, although I don't know why, since a more exact path definition should be working as well.

Comment: The reason is because the Mapserver configure script knows where the Proj.4 files are installed with respect to the base install path, that is `/usr`. Includes are in `/usr/include` but binaries are in `/usr/bin` and so on. Proj.4 doesn't have a "pkg-config" executable like GDAL.

Comment: There's a reason why most people use compiled binary packages from distributions :-) `yum install curl-devel`. You will need to do this for all libraries that are missing.

Comment: Saw that. Well I thought I have all the necessary libs installed, but turned out now. In this case I only had libcurl installed, not libcurl-devel. Concerning binaries, MapServer doesn't have one. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Judging from the last few lines of output:

```
checking for g++... no
checking for c++... no
checking for gpp... no
checking for aCC... no
checking for CC... no
checking for cxx... no
checking for cc++... no
checking for cl.exe... no
checking for FCC... no
checking for KCC... no
checking for RCC... no
checking for xlC_r... no
checking for xlC... no
checking whether we are using the GNU C++ compiler... no
checking whether g++ accepts -g... no
checking whether the C++ compiler works... configure: error: g++ cannot compile
```

you are missing the `g++` compiler and you should be able to install it with

```
yum install gcc-c++
```

You will need also GDAL/OGR and the Proj.4 library. In general, follow the step-by-step instructions at http://www.mapserver.org/installation/unix.html#compiling

Comment: Yeah, but why does it say then: `checking whether we are using the GNU C++ compiler... no`?

Comment: Alright, it solved THAT problem, thanks.. now I have another error in my configure script, don't know whether I should open up a new question.

Comment: If it is again related to something missing, it should be ok to rephrase the question as "What packages to I need to install on CentOS to compile MapServer from source"